# Add request ID to promethus label

Tags: logging, prometheus, web-frontend

I want to store the frontend logs into promethus, an example of frontend log metric looks like this:

```
{
  name: 'fcp',
  Labels:
    - pageName
    - traceID
    - userAgent
}
{
  name: 'component_render_times',
  Labels:
    - componentID
    - pageName
    - traceID
    - userAgent
}
```

the traceID will be different for every page visit, it is unchanged if user stay at the same page. My question is: will this cause cardinality explosion? if so, is there an alternative? I want to analysis the time series data for every traceID, like is the performance get worse if the page openned for days? whats the total components it rendered for that page? if some data point's performance metric very bad, I need the traceid to find more related metrics to find out whats wrong with it

Comment: it can lead to cardinality explosion. I don't have enough info about front-end logging and metrics aggregation, but maybe you need to send logs to FCM or something instead. You can store metrics with lower cardinality like page, etc. Plus, I guess userAgent can lead to cardinality explosion too.

Comment: AMK is right: your idea will very much lead to cardinality explosion. Traceid being basically unique per visit will lead to drastic rate of time series creation and very-very bad performance of Prometheus. Based on your description, I'd dig into logging solutions. Loki, for example, is similar to Prometheus, but designed around storing logs with its workarounds for big number of different labels (just be sure to use dynamic labels).